# MYSQL wrong data inserted

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with my SQL query. I'm trying to insert data into table, but it seems like it put wrong value for one column.

Here is my query:

```
INSERT INTO va_users_points (user_id, order_id, points_amount, points_action, points_type, admin_id_added_by, admin_id_modified_by, date_added)
VALUES ('16772', '152424', '49', '1', '2', '0', '0', '2015-04-20 12:22:03')
```

The problem with column `points_amount`. In my query, it's 49. The DATA Type of this column in MYSQL table is `INT(11)`. But, it inserts 490 value. Why it could be?

Here is my database structure

```
'points_id' INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
'user_id' INT(11) NULL DEFAULT '0',
'order_id' INT(11) NULL DEFAULT '0',
'order_item_id' INT(11) NULL DEFAULT '0',
'points_amount' INT(11) NULL DEFAULT '0',
'points_action' INT(11) NULL DEFAULT '0',
'points_type' INT(11) NULL DEFAULT '0',
'admin_id_added_by' INT(11) NULL DEFAULT '0',
'admin_id_modified_by' INT(11) NULL DEFAULT '0',
'date_added' DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
'date_modified' DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL
```

Comment: datatype is INT(11) and you are inserting string type?

Comment: You where asking why `INT(11)` allowed the 49 value?

Comment: @Rahul It's no problem

Comment: Are there any triggers that probably multiply the value?

Comment: can you share table structure?

Comment: I`m not understand why 49 has additional '0', when inserting into table

Comment: @fancyPants, it may be and probably DB engine will do a implicit conversion but is that all required? If it's numeric type then there is no point in inserting a string type ... right?

Comment: Here is my DB structure
`
 'points_id' INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 'user_id' INT(11) NULL DEFAULT '0',
 'order_id' INT(11) NULL DEFAULT '0',
 'order_item_id' INT(11) NULL DEFAULT '0',
 'points_amount' INT(11) NULL DEFAULT '0',
 'points_action' INT(11) NULL DEFAULT '0',
 'points_type' INT(11) NULL DEFAULT '0',
 'admin_id_added_by' INT(11) NULL DEFAULT '0',
 'admin_id_modified_by' INT(11) NULL DEFAULT '0',
 'date_added' DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 'date_modified' DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL
`

Comment: Try one thing insert with zerofill, is you have in your database 00000000490 you have the problem in your code or in other part.

Comment: @Rahul Yes, there's no point. But it's not uncommon to do so. I wouldn't be surprised if many frameworks actually do it to avoid having to check which datatype the column is.

Comment: @volodymyr3131 You have to come around with more information. Please check for triggers or other parts of your code where the value might be changed.

Comment: It seems like it has changed in anouther script :( So many time was wasted.
And in that, the framework just put wrong type of data into the DB. I think it may caused the problem, because when I changed the inserted data type to int, all inserted fine!  Thanks you all for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see, there is no way this situation can occur except if there is a `AFTER INSERT` trigger defined on this table `va_users_points` which is doing this manipulation behind the scene as already commented by @fancypants.

Check this fiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4b1fb/1) which proves that there is nothing wrong with your `INSERT` statement.

To check if really a trigger is defined or not use the below SQL statement

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TRIGGERS
WHERE TRIGGER_SCHEMA='your_database_name' 
AND EVENT_OBJECT_TABLE='va_users_points';
```

Comment: I had run this query, but it returns empty result(

Comment: then you dont hace triggers. Try zerofill to see that the extra 0 is for code and not for porblem with int (11)

Comment: @volodymyr3131, can you post the select query result of that row? are you sure you haven't updated that particular row?

Comment: It only return empty result, with no data(

Comment: But, when inserting 0, it doesn`t add additional '0' to it